# Only single netty thread is running

Tags: multithreading, netty, worker

I am using ***Netty camel-netty:jar:2.10.0.redhat-60024***.
Below is my configuration of Netty listener

> netty:tcp://10.1.33.204:9001?textline=true&autoAppendDelimiter=true&delimiter=LINE&keepAlive=true&synchronous=false&orderedThreadPoolExecutor=false&sendBufferSize=2000&receiveBufferSize=2000&decoderMaxLineLength=2000&workerCount=20

Here I see based on debug log , Netty is creating only one worker threads , so incoming mesages are blocked until existing message is processed.

Like:

> 2014-08-23 12:36:48,394 | DEBUG | w I/O  worker #5 | NettyConsumer
>   | ty.handlers.ServerChannelHandler   85 | 126 -
>   org.apache.camel.camel-netty - 2.10.0.redhat-60024

Till 5 minute proccess is running but I seee only this thread active. Only when this thread sends reponse it is accepting next request

Comment: Are you using any EventLoopGroups?

Comment: No, I am not configurating any EventLoopGroups. Using outof box features of Camel.as per [link]http://camel.apache.org/netty.html

Comment: Is the next request being sent to the server over the same TCP connection as the original request?

Comment: Yes, It is on the same connection coming back to back.

Answer (score 0):

For TCP, Netty creates a number of worker threads, and assigns each connection to a specific worker thread. All events for that channel are handled by that single thread (note it can be more complex, but that's sufficient for this answer).

It sounds like you're processing your message in the Netty worker thread. Therefore you're blocking processing of any further events on that connection, and all other connections assigned to the worker thread, until your process returns.

Netty is actually creating multiple worker threads. You can see in the debug message that your channel is being handled by I/O worker 5. Netty will create 2 * Runtime.availableProcessors by default but each connection is handled by a single thread unless you intervene.

It's not clear whether you can process requests concurrently and out of order, or whether ordering is important. If ordering is important you can tell camel to use the ordered thread pool executor. This will process the request in a separate thread pool, but subsequent requests on the same connection will still be blocked by the first requests.

If ordering is not important you have a few options. Given that camel appears to be using Netty 3, and allows you to create a custom pipeline, you could use Netty's MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor to process requests concurrently. Perhaps take look at [What happens when shared MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor's threshold is reached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840524/what-happens-when-shared-memoryawarethreadpoolexecutors-threshold-is-reached/9844255#9844255) if you do this.

Camel may offer other mechanisms to help but I'm not overly familiar with Camel. The SEDA component might be a good place to start.